Why does mixing an image texture with transparency affects the brightness/color of other material?
I'm trying to paste a custom PNG image (think of a chess board where black is 100% transparent and white is 100% opaque) over existing material that has a blue color. I mean there's no black, it is just an example to explain there are alternate fully transparent (no black or white or any color data) and fully opaque (white) areas on the image. (If I would upload that sample texture image here, you'd see nothing because transparent areas have no data, and the white would just not be visible because S.E. background is also white. Example image is on imgur link: https://imgur.com/8vFzWzO
I'm also using a Mix Color node to try different blending modes. And eventually I use a Mix Shader node.
In the two images I've attached, you'll see one has low Fac. value while the other has higher Fac. value. Higher value displays more of the texture image but also darkens the blue color to dark blue.


If I try to apply similar blending modes like Overlay or Screen or Color Dodge in any photo editing apps, it doesn't affect the color of the layer at bottom which aligns with the transparent areas of layer at top.
Further, blending modes on Mix Color node doesn't seem to be working like photo editing apps.
Two ways I know to fix this "issue" is that you just connect alpha of image texture to Fac. of Shader Mix node. OR you tweak the color again to make it similar to it was before.
But I'm curious why this affects the color/brightness of the color? I want to know if it's expected behavior and then proceed to what I want to achieve using the "right way".

If it also helps, the purpose of understanding it is that: I want to apply a Noise or Voronoi texture on that color, without affecting the color brightness. Is it even possible? When I try, I notice the same issue, the color becomes darker even where there is more transparency in the Voronoi texture:


Stupid question: do I understand it correctly that you have a chess board kind of texture and the black parts are transparent? And then you reduce the transparency and wonder why semi-transparent black darkens the underlying blue color? I'd say because semi-transparent black is also semi-opaque, so the black is showing over the blue.

@GordonBrinkmann I'm not sure you understood correctly about the texture. Maybe I explained poorly. Black parts are 100% transparent. I mean there's no black, it was just an example. Chess board is just an example to explain there are alternate fully transparent and fully opaque areas on the image.

After that, I'm not reducing transparency. I'm just adjusting the Fac. value on shader. And I understand that white areas of texture may affect the color that align with those areas, but the fully transparent area would always remain transparent irrespective of Fac. value? But that also affects the color brightness/darkness. That's what I don't understand.

The Fac value basically mixes the amount how much the second shader occludes the first shader, so it is kind of the opacity of the second shader. A higher value makes it less transparent, thus the black parts are darkening the blue. The "fully transparent" part is not transparent since you are not using the Alpha channel of the image texture. The Color output of the Image Texture only provides RGB values, no alpha.

@GordonBrinkmann Ah I think I got it. So it's normal if I use the inbuilt Noise or Voronoi textures above exiting color shader and they make the color darker when mixing? And if I have to make the color again a bit brighter, I have to manually adjust the color again? (Because in those noise textures, you don't have the luxury of alpha).

Well, in such noise textures, what determines which areas should be more or less transparent...? The brightness of the noise? Then plug this in the Fac value, maybe adjust it with a Color Ramp, a Map Range or a Mix Color node or others. Sorry, don't mean to be rude, but it sounds as if you do not really know much about combining textures, mixing them by alpha or other manipulations and multi-layer texturing. I would rather suggest you watch tutorials on texturing in Blender.

I mean how do we control the darkness or brightness of the main color (e.g., the blue in my example) when we apply another texture over it by mixing shades . I understand we can control the noise texture's colors that will affect blue color too. But I want to ask about controlling the main blue color. Isn't there any way that blue color's brightness stays intact? Or the only way is to tweak it manually after you've applied the noise textures? For example, if I increased Fac. it becomes more darker, then I select color wheel in blue color's shader node and make it brighter blue again.

I think I know the basic approaches of what I want to achieve. But I'm not sure if it's the right way.
